# TCP Reconnect to Unknown Address with Websocket when there is no Internet

Tags: proxy, websocket

I have used `ProcMon.exe` to see what happens to my application when there is no internet. My application is an `electron` application that makes use of websocket to connect to backend service resides in other computer.

FYI, the example of websocket address is `ws://10.5.14.72:8080/Model`.

AFAIK, HTTP request from websocket will go through proxy server if there is one exist(please correct me I am wrong).

FYI, when there is no internet, the application reacts very slowly as it keeps reconnecting to some unknown address as shown in `ProcMon.exe` which i believe were proxies but i can't find in `internet options`. Below is the details:

```
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50074 -> 203.208.39.198:https    SUCCESS
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50075 -> 203.208.39.198:https    SUCCESS
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50077 -> 203.208.39.199:https    SUCCESS
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50078 -> 203.208.39.199:https    SUCCESS
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50077 -> 203.208.39.199:https    SUCCESS
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50078 -> 203.208.39.199:https    SUCCESS
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50080 -> 203.208.39.193:https    SUCCESS
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50081 -> 203.208.39.193:https    SUCCESS
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50080 -> 203.208.39.193:https    SUCCESS
TCP Reconnect x.x.x.x:50081 -> 203.208.39.193:https    SUCCESS
```

These connecting attempts happen for few minutes before it finally reaches the target address.
So, can I know whether these `203.208.39.xxx:https` addresses represent proxies?

Comment: I can tell you that the machine operating at 203.208.39.193 is either operated by google or proxying your connection to a server operated by google.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, can I know how do you know it was google? FYI, the client's site is in China

Comment: I connected to it with SSL and didn't send any SNI information, and it authenticated with a certificate issued to Google.

Comment: Hi @DavidSchwartz, thanks a lot, i think you did solve my question. My application is a bunch of htmls and js which is bundled as an desktop app using `electron` and I did use google's font in my application.